# Unable to connect to PI despite nmap shows open port

Tags: networking, internet

I have a PI 4 with ethernet connection and I am unable to connect to the pi from any external connections (SSH, VNC, or Nginx). All external connection results in `connection refused` but I can access these services just fine within the Pi.

I did a nmap scan on which returned this:

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-02 22:28 EST
Nmap scan report for dhcp-234-248.resnet.purdue.edu (128.211.234.248)
Host is up (0.033s latency).
Not shown: 96 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
25/tcp   filtered smtp
80/tcp   open     http
5900/tcp open     vnc

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.48 seconds
```

So IP address is accessible but I can't access the services?

Also, there are no `iptables` or `ufw` installed.

Anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: is `128.211.234.248` the IP address of the Pi? Unusual for a pi to be directly connected to the internet like that, but, who knows with `.edu`

Comment: Yes, it is, our school's internet is weird. All devices connected by the ethernet are automatically exposed to the internet, with all the ports forwarded with their own unique IP address (I think).

Comment: `(I think)` - important that you **know for sure** - seems like you may be wrong :p but, `ip a` on the pi shows that address?

Comment: Yes it indeed shows the same IP address

Comment: Also, Connecting the ethernet cable to my laptop allow RDP connections from the internet.

Comment: when you try and ssh, are you using the IP address, or the dhcp-234-248... name? Are you attempting ssh from inside the school network? or from outside?

Comment: Also.... if all those ports really are exposed, I would suggest moving your ssh off of port 22 and to something else, also make sure passwords are good(or remove password remote access, and only use KeyPair to acccess)

Comment: I use the IP address when connecting with ssh. I tried to connect from both inside the school network and outside but neither worked (the Nmap scan is from outside of the school network).

Comment: Connection refused is caused by one of three things: 1. Wrong IP address, 2. Right IP address wrong port, 3. Right IP address, right port, listener not listening. Three things to check. Use `sudo netstat -tlnpu | grep 22` to see if sshd is listening. Use `sudo systemctl enable ssh; sudo systemctl start ssh` to get sshd running.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
As it turns out, when I installed Docker on my machine, it automatically added the following records to the `host` file.

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
128.211.195.246 host.docker.internal
128.211.195.246 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

and when I tried to ssh into the Pi via IP, ssh will resolve to `host.docker.internal`, resulting in a `connection refused error`. Removing these records from `hosts` file allowed me to connect to the PI.

The reason why that issue did not show up during nmap is that I had to use my cloud-hosted server to run the scan which has a perfectly fine `hosts` file.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a docker's feature or not. If not, should I file a bug report to docker?

Comment: does "on my machine" refer to the pi?

Comment: It’s referring to my laptop which I was trying to connect to the PI from.

Comment: so, it was an issue on the laptop, not on the raspberry pi

Comment: Yes. The docker installation on the laptop lead to incorrect resolution of PI’s IP address.